# how to make data consistent when return it from API

Tags: json, laravel, api, object

my data in database have no consistent form, some data looks like this

```
{
 'name': 'some name',
 'age': 'some age'
}
```

and another looks like this

```
[
   {
   'name': 'some name',
   'age': 'some age'
   }
]
```

even others are looking like this

```
[
   [
     {
      'name': 'some name',
      'age': 'some age'
     }
   ]
]
```

and it can be any number of objects

I am working on an API with Laravel, and the client will want to work with consistent data, how can I make the data consistent when returning from the ApI?

**EDIT**
My intention is to convert all responses from API to array of objects as in the 2nd example, can I use API resources and how can I handle the inconsistency of the data.

Comment: "How can I make the data consistent?": test your code, it seems that you are not doing/having a good validation, so you have either a "bug" or you are not validating some input. Once you solve that problem, I recommend you to create a `command` that will run or look for this data (wrong format) and fix it, so you can finally fix everything.

Comment: can you recommend a way to find and fix (wrong format) data to look like data in the 2nd example

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to run over each model before your fix (date) and see each model. Other possibility could be to still use the date filter but use `like` and `[{%` or similar search.